# Update the datasource for an adjacent cell when selection change occurs in a DataGridView Combo box cell

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I have a dataGridView with comboBox dropdowns for each cell. 
I would like to update the datasource for cell[0,1] when the value in cell[0,0] changes.
I created an event handler for the 'selection changed events' on the datagrid view.
When the selection changed event occurs, it fires the event, and the sender is the DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl type.

How do I know which column triggered the selection changed event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This walk through shows the example for your scenario.

http://asimsajjad.blogspot.in/2009/09/raising-dropdownlist.html